# Blender 2.81 and later crashing when adding more lights in Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Anyone experiencing Blender 2.81 and later crashing when adding more lights in EEVEE? More exactly when I add the 4th light to my scene. It works perfectly for 3 lights.

Upon further investigation it's related to if shadows are disabled or not for every added lights. I can add as many lights as I want as long as shadows are disabled, but if more than 3 lights have shadows enabled it crashes or get strange color shading phenomena.

It works using Cycles. My computer specs:

- Mac mini 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
- 16GB RAM
- Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB

Comment: Hello! Is Blender crashing or freezing for a very long time? Also, are you in rendered view mode in the viewport? I'm asking because of your computer specs. Double-check that there aren't any typos because 2.3 GHz clock speed for a processor is very, very low.

Comment: Hi, as soon as I add the 4th light with shadows enabled it freezes immediately and after around 5 to 10 seconds it crashes with a crash report sent to Apple. It’s 2,3 GHz chock frequency. And I’m in rendered view. I tried to delete everything and just have the lights there and still got same result. However if I start from scratch ( from a new file) and just add the 4 lights I cannot reproduce it

Comment: Possibly a GPU error? 2.81 requires a lot of GPU power for certain scenes, and Intel HD is not entirely meant for CGI. Also, I use a 1.68 GHz CPU and I am fine. It is probably not that.

Comment: I personally suspect that some of the system resources are being completely exhausted or something, but it's just speculation. It probably is a bug. Try reporting it to the devs at https://developer.blender.org/ , this seems to be more up their alley.

Comment: I have similar issues, but with more than 41 lights. The moment I add more lights and turn on the lighting, or if I have less lights than 41 and I try entering VR view and I turn on Lighting it crashes immediately 

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz
Installed RAM 32.0 GB
64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1660 Ti